# 2D Array access violation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I tried debugging the following code, and I get an "access violation" error. I do not understand why the second loop fails when accessing the second row of elements while the first loop is able to access all the elements.

I'm messing up the `*`, `&` and `[]`, but can't figure it out.

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

void a(const int* data, unsigned int nElements, unsigned int nColumns) {

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nElements; ++i)
        std::cout << data[i];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nElements / nColumns; ++i)
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < nColumns; ++j)
            std::cout << (&data)[i][j];
}

int main() {
    int arr[2][5] = {
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    a(*arr, 2 * 5, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do a bit more? It's kinda unclear.

Comment: the real issue is here: (&data)[i].  because data is a single element in the argument, &data is a pointer to a single element.  this means that i>0 is a problem.  a multi-dimensional array is really a block of memory, and when you do [i][j] on a multi-dimensional array, the compiler treats it differently than [i][j] on an array of pointers.  [i][j] on multidimensional array is the same as [i*numcolumns+j].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lost all type information once you are in your `a` function, so you cannot expect the subscript operators to work as you don't say what size the array has. Specify the size in the parameter listing and subscripting will work:

```
void a(int const (&data)[2][5]) {
  for (auto const& row : data)
    for (auto i : row)
      ::std::cout << i << " ";
  ::std::cout << ::std::endl;
}
```

You can then even go crazy and change the prototype to:

```
template <size_t R, size_t C>
void a(int const (&data)[R][C]) {
```

So it works for all 2D arrays.

Comment: After removing the asterisk when passing the argument -- `a(arr, 2 * 5, 5);`, and specifying the size in the parameter like in your example, also removing the ampersand when accessing data, I was able to use two subscript operators.

I didn't think it was out of bounds, as the first loop was able to access the same memory; and that was the question which I had that you answered in the first part of your first sentence. However, I still do not understand what you mean by "lost all type information." Can you please expand on that, or share a source where I can read more about it. Thank you.

Comment: @user2570380: When you say `a[1][2]` (for example) you need the type system in order for `a[1]` to resolve to the correct address (which is the element 0 of array 1). This is due to the fact that the address depends on the *size* of the second dimension. If you have a 2x5 `int` array, every increment in the first subscript has to "jump" 5 `int` values. You can only do this with the static type matching the runtime type. If all you have is an `int*` how should the compiler or cpu know what it is supposed to do with `a[1][2]`?

Answer (score 2):

`(&data)[i]` is clearly bogus. `data` is a variable which is not an array. It's legal to write `(&data)[0]` and treat a variable like an array with one element. However, if `i > 0` then you attempt to access memory after where `data` is stored, which is not any memory you own. (Don't mix up the pointer `data` with the things it is pointing to).

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
std::cout << data[i * nColumns + j];
```

This `*` is of course multiplication, not the dereference operator. When calling this function you are "flattening" the array by treating it as if it were a 10-element 1-D array, so you need to use arithmetic to work out the required index.

Finally, in the function call, `*arr` should be `(int *)&arr` or `(int *)arr`. What you have actually written is `arr[0]`, which is a 5-element array. It's an out-of-bounds access to try and read more than 5 elements from it in your function. In practice, compilers don't try to detect out-of-bounds accesses for efficiency reasons and it will appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

`*arr` is equal to `*(arr + 0)` which is equal to `arr[0]`. `arr[0]` only has 5 `nElements`, not 10. Call the function like this:

```
a(*arr, 5, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line in the double for loop to:

```
std::cout << data[i * nColumns + j];
```